# Is it possible to terminate a HTTP connection to the user without stopping computations (Next.js)?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, next.js

I have a Next.js endpoint that does a slow query. I want the user not to wait till it finishes the query.

Is it possible to terminate the HTTP connection but continue computations?

I know that this can be done using threads. But threads are not easy to program. Is there another way?

For example, in Express there is `res.end()`. Can I use it in Next.js to stop communicating with the client but continue the computations?